# Angular date transform based on chosen time zone which works local machine but not on server

Tags: angular

I am using the below code snippet to transform the date in angular, which works fine on local machines but if the same code is deployed on the server it's not working.
Note: on local and server I am getting same date API response

```
const date = "2021-11-03T07:25:41.493";

this.datePipe.transform(date,'MM/dd/yyyy | h:mm a', '+0530')
```

on local machine it shows date 11/03/20201 | 1:17 PM
and on the server, it shows  11/03/2021 | 7:47 AM

the expected result is it should same date on local and server machine, 11/03/20201 | 1:17 PM

If anyone could help, it will be really helpful.
Thanks

Comment: How are you parsing the date on the server, in other words. How are you viewing the date? Are you using any library there?

Comment: no, I am not using any library to parse data

Comment: try using UTC date format instead of iso for input

Comment: @JatinParate, the date is in UTC format only, we are converting it to configured timezone, which is  GMT+0530, in above example